# How to troubleshoot CSS issue that only appears in Safari Mobile?

Tags: css, safari, mobile-safari

I keep having CSS issues that only appear on deployment when viewed from an iPhone. I cannot replicate the issues from a Desktop/Laptop browser no matter what I try (resizing, using responsive design mode, etc.) My current solution is to guess a fix, deploy it and then check. Obviously this is horribly slow / inefficient. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using safari on a desktop to inspect the elements of a connected iPhone running safari is a thing ;)
https://www.browserstack.com/guide/how-to-inspect-element-on-iphone